# Issue registering or copying a file from program files to system32

Tags: batch-file, dll, command-prompt, regsvr32

I am trying to register several dll files in order to make a program work.
However, I am facing a major problem:

I made a batch file which registers all dll files on one go with

```
for %x in ("%programfiles(x86)%\folder\*.dll") do regsvr32 %x
```

and I get the following error multiple times:

```
The module "C:\Program" failed to load...
```

I also tried to copy said files to system32 and then register them there but have the same error message.

Is there a way I can finally get it to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to put double quotes around `%x` as the file path contains spaces.

Command line:

```
for %x in ("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\folder\*.dll") do %SystemRoot%\System32\regsvr32.exe "%x"
```

Batch file:

```
for %%x in ("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\folder\*.dll") do %SystemRoot%\System32\regsvr32.exe "%%x"
```

Run in a command prompt window `for /?` and read all help pages output.

Comment: I used your suggestion and it worked! However, I get some errors now most having to do with the program being able to load the file but not registering it. What can I do about that?

Comment: I can't answer this new question without inside knowledge of application code and used DLLs. In general it is no good sign if the DLLs of an application must be manually registered with `regsvr32`. This should be done by the installer of the application or by the application itself. Registering DLLs in `HKLM\Software\Classes` requires write permissions, i.e. `Administrator` or `TrustedInstaller` account must be used. You could run your batch file *as administrator* and see if this helps.

Comment: Well, it goes like this: this program was made by the Mexican government in order to facilitate invoice procedures. I am making a program for a company to facilitate weighing procedures and tickets. Said tickets are usually done by the government's program, but I am tasked to make the movement automatically in my program. I have done lots of research and it can be done. I am working on a sample program provided by the programmers but I cannot get to work due to the necessary dll not loading :/

Comment: Then I would suggest you give us the actual errors instead of just mentioning that they exist.

Comment: This program came with a number of sample programs to use their sdk in various languages. I use a VB6 sample. I downloaded and opened it without a problem. The problem comes when I try to run it. I get an error saying "File MGW_SDK.dll not found". I try to make a reference of it and I get another error saying I can't do that. I tried registering the file I needed but got the error saying it loaded but not registered it. I figured it had dependencies with other dll's so I made the batch file I mentioned and am getting many of those messages. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 2):

By any chance, by `%x` did you mean `%%x` for batch files?

And a general safety tip, escape the parentheses in your path with `^`, like so:

```
for %%x in ("%programfiles^(x86^)%\folder\*.dll") do regsvr32 "%%~x"
```

---

edit: added quotes to `%%x` parameter by @mofi's note.

Comment: I tried using %%x, like you suggested and I get the warning "%%x was not expected". Taking it out makes nothing happen.

Comment: If you run it at the command line directly, use one percent sign: `%x`. If it's in a .bat file, you need to use two: `%%x` because for some reason when it's run from a batch file, it evaluates the expression first, which changes `%%` in to `%`.

Comment: There is no need to escape the parentheses at `(x86)` since they are in between `""`; you should write `"%%~x"` instead of `"%%x"` to avoid double-double-quotes; perhaps `"%%~fx"` would even be better, so you can run your batch file from everywhere you like...